# Bash checking if file exists and then check for a substring in the file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, rhel

I want to check if file exists and then check for a substring in the file

```
if [ -f /etc/abc.conf ]; then
   if [ grep 'abc.conf' -e 'host.com' ]
    test = 'PASS'
   else 
    test = 'FAIL'
   fi
else
   echo "File doesnot exist"
fi

echo $test
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do the same

Comment: Are you asking because this snippet doesn't work? Try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to identify the bad and missing syntax.

Comment: There is a better way, because what you have now is simply broken.

Comment: @BenjaminW. How is that a duplicate? There's not a single word about non-existing files among the answers :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your grep might support the `-s` argument:

```
   -s, --no-messages
          Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
```

So something like this should work:

```
grep -qs 'abc.conf' '/etc/abc.conf' && test='PASS' || test='FAIL'
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep returns 2 if file does not exist or is not readable, and 1 if the string is not found.

```
grep -qs '<string>' file.txt
res=$?
if [ $res -eq 0 ]; then
  test='PASS'
elif [ $res -eq 1 ]; then
  test='FAIL'
elif [ $res -eq 2 ]; then
  echo "Cannot read file"
else
  echo "Unrecognized return code ($res) from grep"
fi
```

Comment: Or `case $? in 0) test='PASS' ;;` etc. (you have extra spaces around `=`, by the way)

Comment: That's what I get for copy-and-paste! :D  I'll fix it.  Thanks.

Comment: `case` is good, but I did not want to add syntax he might not know.